# Apache - Very high load/bandwidth and unusual pattern of requests

Tags: apache-2.2, php, wordpress, bandwidth, high-volume

I am a web developer and have this server that's being used as a development machine of sorts. So, my experience with Apache is that I can fiddle around and get basic stuff done / google stuff to get the answers I need.

Over the weekend, we had a lot of load on the server to the order of 1000 times the average bandwidth usage. My Apache access logs has lines and lines that look similar to below.

```
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/10/a.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1671717 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/10/b.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2682375 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/07/c.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1009591 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/d.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 365209 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/e.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 410225 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/10/b.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2682375 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/f.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 446529 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/g.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2727018 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/h.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2504361 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/i.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 520036 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/j.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2589152 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/j.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 4665478 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/07/c.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1009591 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/k.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1936692 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/l.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2777877 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/eels.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2451371 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/cows91.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1297337 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/m.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2551047 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/n.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2977841 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/e.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 410225 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:15 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/o.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1999738 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/p.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1994689 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/d.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 365209 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/10/a.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1671717 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/10/b.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2682375 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/07/c.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1009591 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/d.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 365209 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/e.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 410225 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/10/a.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1671717 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/10/b.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2682375 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/07/c.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1009591 "-" "-"
81.12.34.56 - - [30/Oct/2011:01:08:16 +0200] "GET /wp-content/uploads/photos/d.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 365209 "-" "-"
```

The same set of images are being requested over and over again by *my own server*! Also, yes the user agent is just a dash.

- This downloading of files starts again as soon as I restart the server.
- I found a couple of lines in access log where `/feed` is being requested by the user agent  `"-" "Apple-PubSub/65.28"`. I checked the user agent and this seems to be someone asking their Mac OS to manage their feeds.
- The site has been built using WordPress. However, there are no plugins etc. installed.
- I am using the functions `getimagesize` and the library timthumb (Php). Could any of those be causing these issues?

Comment: 81.12.34.56 is the only source ? `iptables -A INPUT -s 81.12.34.56 -j DROP`

Comment: But, 81.12.34.56 is also my server's IP address - the server on which this app is hosted. Adding it to IP tables will block the requests - but not solve the problem I'm having.

Comment: Ok, show me the output of `ps auxf` please.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/V5t5Bp01

Comment: Very strange ! Don't know what appending, but be careful with timthumb library, look here: http://wpcandy.com/reports/timthumb-security-vulnerability-discovered